# getSharedPreferences return nullpointerexception on fragment method

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have a getSharedPreferences on my fragment1, and it will load int from previous fragment.

```
public void backButtonWasPressed() {
    settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    .....
}
```

i call fragment1.backButtonWasPressed() and give me force close and error message nullpointerexception on "settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);"

My Logcat :

```
08-28 16:52:21.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 16:52:21.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4412): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 16:52:21.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4412):     at pkh.apps.Fragment1.backButtonWasPressed(Fragment1.java:324)
08-28 16:52:21.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4412):     at pkh.apps.KajianUtama.onBackPressed(KajianUtama.java:71)
08-28 16:52:21.828: E/AndroidRuntime(4412):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2131)
```

Line 324 on Fragment1 is : settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

My Main SherlockFragmentActivity :

```
public class KajianUtama extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
....
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment1 = (Fragment1) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    fragment1.backButtonWasPressed();
}
.....
```

}

My Fragment1 :

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{
....
   public void backButtonWasPressed() {
     settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
     c = settings.getInt("numRun",0);
     Log.d("back pressed", "c " + c);
   }
...
}
```

Please give me a solution to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: If it loads a string then why the default value is 0? Should be `""` or `null`.

Comment: sorry, i mean int, i have edited my question

Comment: can u post logs stating that line number and highlighting line number?

Comment: `getActivity()` returns null.

Comment: DIVA and Fouad Wahabi : see updated question above. Thank you.

Comment: is shared pref line points to -->TopikFragment.java:324???@wdyz

Comment: DIVA : TopikFragment --> Fragment1. sorry, edited. And line 324 on Fragment1 is : settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

Comment: it gives error when loading or back press

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the name of your Preference is the same that you use to save it, a best practice is to save a constant `PREFERENCE_NAME="myPreferenceName"` and then use that constant instead of the string.

EDIT

Try in this way

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  fragment1 = (Fragment1) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
  fragment1.backButtonWasPressed(this);
}
```

and then

```
public void backButtonWasPressed(Context context) {
   settings = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
   c = settings.getInt("numRun",0);
   Log.d("back pressed", "c " + c);
}
```

Pass the context to the method

Comment: i have check and cross check the name, and i am sure, it's correct name.

Comment: that way give me an error : "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type KajianUtama". KajianUtama is SherlockFragmentActivity, not Fragment

Comment: your solution is work, my sharedPreferences not return null anymore :D thanks.

Comment: but, on my Fragment1 i want to use some variables on onCreate method to backButtonWasPressed(Context context) method, but it will return null. Besides, some variables was declared on onCreate method. How to use it on backButtonWasPressed?

Comment: The problem is that you use the method, but you don't instantiate the whole object, if you get an instance of it, I think your problems will be solved

Comment: thank you, now i've implement some Pop Stack to solve this problem :)